# Java ensure same Wildcard capture type

Tags: java, generics, types

I get two objects o1: T, o2: Consumer which come from asource that boils down to this:

```java
public interface MySource<T> {
    Class<T> getType();

    Consumer<T> getComsumer();
}
```

I want to feed them back to a generic method that expects both to have the same Type (Parameter).

```
public interface Registry<M> {
    <T extends M> void register(Class<T> type, Consumer<T> consumer);
}
```

From somewhere i get MySource with an unknown type.

Java isn't smart enough to infer, that the existential types are actually the same.

```
public abstract class Example<M> {
    Registry<M> registry;

    static MySource<? extends M> getSrc();

    public <T extends M> void register(Class<T> type) {
        MySource<? extends M> src = getSrc();
        registry.register(src.getType(), src.getComsumer());
    }

> The method register(Class<T>, Consumer<T>) in the type
> Registry<M> is not applicable for the arguments
> (Class<capture#3-of ? extends M>, Consumer<capture#4-of ? extends M>)
```

Do i have to wrap the result in another object? Or is there a nicer way to solve this?

Comment: Looks like you should pass in a `MySource<T>` instead of the separate parameters, then the two can't be different.

Comment: Show the complete method or class that contains the call to `registry.register(...)`, especially the method declaration or class declaration (do these have type parameters?).

Comment: @AndyTurner: I know that would solve the problem, but it wouldn't make sense in my architecture.

Comment: @Jesper: i will try to make a minimal example and update.

Comment: You should read *Effective Java 2nd Ed* Item 28: "Use bounded wildcards to increase API flexibility". Specifically, the bit which says "Do not use wildcard types as return types". Your problems have arisen because of returning `MySource<? extends M>` from `getSrc()`.

Comment: The Class where the wildcards are returned from is an interface for what you could maybe call a partial type-isomorphism - and I dont know until runtime, which types are in the domain - hence the wildcard in return types - I was not able to come up with a way to get rid of them (I will post another Question on this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your bounds around:

```
MySource<M> src;
Registry<? super M> registry;
```

Then your `registry.register(src.getType(), src.getComsumer());` works just fine.

You might want a little wrapper method to do that:

```
<M> void wrapRegister(MySource<M> src, Registry<? super M> registry) {
  registry.register(src.getType(), src.getComsumer());
}
```

Then:

```
MySource<? extends M> src = ...;
Registry<M> registry = ...;
wrapRegister(src, registry);
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/iVm5Uu)

Comment: I wrapped my applicaton in a minimal class as @Jesper requested. If you want you can adjust your answer accordingly.

Comment: I answered the question asked. I don't want to chase your moving goalposts.

Comment: Apologies - I'm not exactly sure what you mean by moving goalpost, but the question from my original post have not changed: as stated simply wrapped the application in a class for the sake of clarity, as was requested.
I had imagined it might be of help to others who stumble across this post, if the accepted answer would match, however did not mean to waste your time.

Comment: Your question was quite clear: you had a `MySource<? extends M>` and a `Registry<M>`; I gave you an answer based on that. There's no need for a wrapper class to illustrate this, so I'm disinclined to edit my answer because [you've edited your question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_the_goalposts).

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed, Java isn't smart enough for this. However, you can use reflection to call your method:

```
try {
    Method registerMethod = registry.getClass().getMethod("register", Class.class, Consumer.class);
    registerMethod.invoke(registry, src.getType(), src.getConsumer());
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    // generics didn't match or something else went wrong, you can catch specific Exceptions from reflective .invoke() method   
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you - I'd like to try to avoid reflection, if it is possible. In case there is no other option for me I will resort to this solution.

Comment: Reflection is not a good solution to this - the compiler has type checking for a reason, and you're sidestepping it, as well as sidestepping the checking for the existence of the `Registry.register(Class, Consumer)` method. You'd be better off using raw types than reflection - at least the compiler would still check for the method existence. But you don't need to use either.